# Using LDAP Authentication but ModelBackend Authorisation

Tags: django, ldap

I've been working on a Django app that authenticates against an LDAP. I've created permissions and groups in the admin interface. In development mode I have both back-ends active

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Django tries authenticating across all of its authentication back-ends. Regardless of where it succeeds it uses the ModelBackend Authorization (permissions and groups) granted to the users.

But when disabling 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' Django does not use the standard Authorization methods. In production environment I want users to authenticate against LDAP only.

**My question:**

Is there an option to disable ModelBackend authorization but still use ModelBackend Authorization.

**EDIT**

First note in the [docs of django-auth-ldap](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/_static/versions/1.0.19/index.html#auth-ldap-global-options) :

Note LDAPBackend does not inherit from ModelBackend. It is possible to use LDAPBackend exclusively by configuring it to draw group membership from the LDAP server. However, if you would like to assign permissions to individual users or add users to groups within Django, you’ll need to have both backends installed:

But I'm still puzzled. There is no technical reason for this. When both backends activated, and authenticating against LDAP, Django is still able to use the Django permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was asked quite a while ago, so I hope you found an answer... but to help anyone else who may stumble across this:

> "The permissions given to the user will be the superset of all permissions returned by all backends. That is, Django grants a permission to a user that any one backend grants."

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends

This means that it is falling through and checking all permissions/perms methods in all of the backends, even though you were authenticated using the LDAPBackend, Django is pulling permissions/perms from LDAPBackend + ModelBackend and grouping them all together.

If you REALLY REALLY want to be SURE that ModelBackend.authenticate() is never called, you could always just make your own class MyAuth(ModelBackend) inheriting from ModelBackend and override authenticate in that to just always return None. Then you would include this in your settings.py file.